# NPDA for this language with n and n-1

Tags: automata, state-machine, formal-languages, pushdown-automaton

[image]

To draw the transition graph of a NPDA that accepts L, I think one could start this problem by reading an `a`, writing an `a`, then moving right, then doing the same for `b` so that there is some state q<sub>1</sub> that is getting those "ab" movements.  But then how is it possible to get `bb` to have `n-1`?

I have something that I think works but I'm teaching this to myself so maybe someone can show me where the `n` and `n-1` could be done correctly.

EDIT:

But now this should be it --

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple actually. Each time you read "ab", you store a token in the stack. Then after reading "c", you take one from that token. Then for each "bb", you take one token from the stack. When the stack is empty you accept.

For the NPDA itself, it depends how do you define the acceptance. From your question, I don't get what do you mean by "writing an `a`, then moving right". Are you confusing NPDA with a Turing Machine? An NPDA is very similar to an NFA (Non-deterministic Finite Automata) except that it's equipped with a stack, in which you can put stack symbols. Read up more here: http://www.cs.duke.edu/~rodger/courses/cps140/lects/sectnpdaH.pdf

Below is the transition table, assuming stack symbols `{A,Z}` where `Z` is the initial stack symbol. Accept when we are in the only accepting state q<sub>a</sub> and we have finished reading the input tape. Assume that each transition always consume one stack symbol, and if there is no more symbol to be consumed while the NPDA is not in acceptance state, the NPDA does not accept (or reject) the string.

In the table below, the first column represents the state we are currently in and the stack symbol we are reading. Subsequent columns represent the new state and stack symbol pushed to the stack upon reading a particular character in input string (or not reading any character at all with ε)

```
+------++---------+-------+--------+-------+
|      ||    a    |   b   |   c    |   ε   |
+------++---------+-------+--------+-------+
|(q1,Z)|| (q2,Z)  |    -   |    -   |   -   |
+------++---------+-------+--------+-------+
|(q1,A)|| (q2,A)  |    -   | (q3,ε) |   -   |
+------++---------+-------+--------+-------+
|(q2,Z)||    -    |(q1,ZA) |    -   |   -   |
+------++---------+-------+--------+-------+
|(q2,A)||    -    |(q1,AA) |    -   |   -   |
+------++---------+-------+--------+-------+
|(q3,Z)||    -    |   -    |    -   |(qa,ε) |
+------++---------+-------+--------+-------+
|(q3,A)||    -    | (q4,A) |    -   |   -   |
+------++---------+-------+--------+-------+
|(q4,A)||    -    | (q3,ε) |    -   |   -   |
+------++---------+-------+--------+-------+
```

The key idea here is that the number of A in the stack represents how many times the phrase "ab" appears in the input string.

You can see that in reading "a" in state q<sub>1</sub> with stack symbol Z, we push back Z to the stack. Meaning there is still no "ab" detected yet. It will then go to q<sub>2</sub>.

In q<sub>2</sub>, we only accept "b", any other input will cause it to hang (and hence reject). It pushes back the state it read into the stack, plus an additional A, effectively increasing the number of A in the stack by 1, since this transition represents an additional phrase "ab" in the input string.

The state q<sub>3</sub> represents the part after successfully reading "c". Note that transition from q<sub>1</sub> to q<sub>3</sub> must consume A, not Z, since we have the constraint `n >= 1`. Then, upon reading "b", it will go to state q<sub>4</sub> to wait for another "b". Later q<sub>4</sub>, upon reading "b", will consume the stack symbol A, matching

At state q<sub>3</sub> we also want a transition to acceptance state q<sub>a</sub> once we reach stack symbol Z, referring to the state where there are `n` copies of "ab" and `n-1` copies of "bb".

State q<sub>4</sub> only accepts the input string "b" with stack symbol A, representing finding a new phrase "bb" should match one phrase "ab" previously found.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good explanation, +1, but I want to make sure I understand you fully.  I added, what I think is, the way this would work.

Comment: If your "lambda" (or 2?) in your diagram refers to not putting anything into the stack, and that "(ab,1)/1" refers to putting *additional* symbol into the stack, then you've got it. Although I'm not sure whether you should include the boundary case of reading "(ab,Z)" in q_0.

Comment: Thanks I'll definitely go back and look at `(ab,z)/z`, accepted answer.  You know if you've got a moment I happen to be working on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258391/npda-with-exactly-2-states-that-might-need-3-transitions-to-final-state which I already have some idea (that might be quite wrong but hey who knows) and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20232717/disk-cylinder-service-requests-algorithms where I'm going over some disk service algos. If you're interested.

Comment: Added the `(ab,z)/z`, just want to make sure that was the same transition you were talking about.

Comment: Actually you should put (ab,Z)/1Z, meaning after reading stack symbol Z, you pushed Z back, and also you pushed 1 as new stack symbol. And the other transition also. Instead of (ab,1)/1, you should put (ab,1)/11. But you got the idea correct.

Comment: Corrected to include an initial push of `1` onto `z` and `11` on the top of the stack afterwards.  Just want to make sure I understand you correctly.