# NPDA with exactly 2 states that might need 3 transitions to final state

Tags: automata, state-machine, formal-languages, pushdown-automaton

[image]

Let's say we want to draw the transition graph with two states of a NPDA that accepts that language L. And let's also say that this NPDA will have exactly 2 states.  My thinking on this would be to do everything in the first state then use the second state as the grand finale.  Like so:

[image]

But I'm not sure that the lambda transitions will result in `q1` or if there is a better way to do this, which there likely is a better way since I'm trying to teach this to myself.  Perhaps someone can get me back on track here?

Comment: This kind of CS theory isn't really on-topic for stackoverflow. You'll have much better luck at http://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Seems like a much better fit for CS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it. You just missed the `n>=1` requirement, since your current NPDA will also accept "acb". And you don't need (b,4)/5, since stack symbol 5 won't be used anyway.

So you need another stack symbol between 1 and 2 to denote whether we have seen "b" before "c".

```
q0-q0         q0-q1
(a,Z)/1Z     (b,3)/λ
(b,1)/2      (b,4)/λ
(b,2)/2      (b,5)/λ
(c,2)/3
(b,3)/4
(b,4)/5
```

Comment: Wonderful +1, I'm just not sure I'm totally understanding you on the last `b`, since `m` could be 1, 2, or 3, so it would seem like that's 3 possible transitions `q0-q1`.  What did I miss?